# Category percent share of total Cognos expresison builder

Tags: analytics, cognos

I am trying to calculate each distinct category share of total sales. However, my calculations end up with adding the share of sales of each category to 1. I've tried both:

[Sales]/Total([Sales] for [Category])

and

CASE WHEN [Category] in ('X','Y','Z')
THEN PERCENTAGE Sales FOR [Category]
ELSE NULL END

Any advice?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the scope for the total needs to be defined

You can try "For report" and that will probably work

Try this:

```
[Sales]/Total([Sales] for report)
```

Answer (score 0):

Percentage([Sales])  or Percentage([Sales] for report) should both work.